# Getting Custom Fiscal Month and Year from Calendar Date

Tags: apex, date, custom-fiscal-year

We have set up a custom fiscal calendar in Salesforce using the standard Fiscal Year functionality located within Company Profile.

Within an Opportunity, I want to convert the close date (which is a calendar date) and get the month and year that that date corresponds to on the custom fiscal calendar. I would like to access this in APEX if possible. I have read about the standard fiscal year functionality within the date function but I have read it is unavailable if you use a custom calendar.

Is there a method I can use to gain the fiscal month and year for the calendar date?

I hope I have explained myself clearly. Thank you in advance for any assistance or advice I am pulling my hair out over it...

Comment: Create a formula fields - works for us

Comment: how `custom` is your custom calendar? each quarter is 3 months, just that Q1 doesn't start on Jan 1? Or something of the ilk 4 - 4 -5 as described in the doc https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_cfy_template.htm&language=en_US

Comment: It's more like 4-5-4-5 but yeah completely custom. Zero logic to it it's all constructed via 4-5-4-5 from my understanding

Comment: have you get solution on this?

Comment: @unidha there is no defined solution using standard functionality. In the end we created a custom object using custom metadata and uploaded our fiscal calendar there, one record for each day. This gave us the ability to convert calendar dates to fiscal dates programmatically (by querying the object)

Comment: @DavidDawson if you create new object for calendar, is it possible for you to link it with Opportunity object in standard page? For example if you want to have fiscal month field to be display in  Opportunity .

Comment: @unidha technically yes but you cannot do this via a formula field. A custom metadata object acts like any other object, but the only difference is how the data is stored (and instead of the suffix being __c it is __mdt). You will have to write a trigger and populate a field on the Opportunity object.